# Can We Store output value from EXECUTE Command into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to store the JSON output of a dynamic stored procedure into a variable so that I can use that output in another stored procedure.

Here is what I'm trying to do: I have a stored procedure that accepts three parameters

```
@CompId, @LanguageCode, @Address OUTPUT
```

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PL].[spGetCompanyAddress]
    @CompId INT,
    @LanguageCode VARCHAR(2),
    @Address VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT [pl].fnFormattedname(@CompId, @CompId,0))
    DECLARE @MultilingualStateName VARCHAR(200) = (dbo.fnGetMultilingualColumns('States', @LanguageCode, 'States'))

    SET @Address = N'SELECT ISNULL((SELECT '
    + '[pl].fnFormattedname('+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CompId)+','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CompId)+',0) AS Name '
    + ',a.Line1'
    + ',a.Line2'
    + ',a.Line3'
    + ',a.City'
    + ',a.PostalCode'
    +','+ @MultilingualStateName +
    + ',p.CompressedPhone'
    +' FROM pl.users u'+
    +' LEFT JOIN pl.Phones p ON u.UserId = p.UserId '
    +'LEFT JOIN pl.Addresses a ON u.UserId = a.UserId'
    +' INNER Join dbo.States s ON s.stateid = a.stateid'
    + ' WHERE u.UserId = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@CompId)
    + ' AND p.phonetypeId = 1'
    + ' AND p.DisplayOrder = 1'
    + ' FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ),''[]'') AS Result' 
    
    EXEC(@Address) 
    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
END
```

I'm calling this with this code:

```
DECLARE @Address VARCHAR(MAX)

EXEC [PL].[spGetCompanyAddress] 10606, 'FR', @Address

SELECT @Address AS Address
```

Output is empty.

I have also have tried with this code, but still get the same output

```
EXEC sp_executesql @Query,
                   N'@Address VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                   @Address OUTPUT;

SELECT @Address AddressValue
```

I want to use the output JSON into another stored procedure's OUTPUT

Comment: Carefuly, what you have above is open to injection (though difficult, I will admit). You need to ensure dynamic statements are properly quoted *using `QUOTENAME`) *and* **parametrised** (using `sp_executesql`). Also, you should really be declaring your lengths for your strings: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: The result of `@Address` would be the dynamic sql, not the result of the execution of that sql (the JSON). Is there an error during execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your stored procedure should look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE . . .
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @sql = '
    <complex SQL statement here>
    ';
    
        -- This is the important part
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                       N'@CompId INT, @LanguageCode VARCHAR(2), @Address VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                       @CompID=@CO@Address=@Address OUTPUT;
        . . .

         EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                            N'@Address VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                            @Address OUTPUT;
    END;
```

When you call the procedure, you should use the same structure:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @pl.spGetCompanyAddress,
     N'@CompId INT, @LanguageCode VARCHAR(2), @Address VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
     @CompID=@CCompID, @LanguageCode=@LanguageCode, @Address=@Address OUTPUT;
```